# Only scroll in one direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, scroll, scrollbar, vertical-scrolling

I have a infinite vertical scrolling bar in unity and I want to suddenly limit the scrolling (in one direction only) when reaching a (variable) threshold.

```
public GameObject MyScrollRectContent;
public float limit = 300;

void Update () {
    if(MyScrollRectContent.transform.localPosition.y >= limit){
        //make it ONLY possible to scroll backwards or not beyond the limit and stop elasticity
    }
```

Any ideas how to limit the infinite scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to use the existing [ScrollRect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ScrollRect.html). It allows scroll in a defined rectangle. You would have to simulate infinity by setting a really big size in one direction, or find a way to seamlessly reset the position if the user goes too far (difficult to do without seeing the jump but might be possible depending on your content).

If this is not an acceptable solution:

To limit the scrolling, you can just set the position to the limit if the user goes too high:

```
void Update () 
{
    if(MyScrollRectContent.transform.localPosition.y >= limit)
    {
        var currentPos = MyScrollRectContent.transform.localPosition;
        MyScrollRectContent.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(currentPos.x, limit, currentPos.z);
    }
}
```

Now if on top of that you want elasticity, it is a bit more tricky: Somewhere, your script must currently set `MyScrollRectContent.transform.localPosition`. Instead of doing that, set a `targetYPosition`. You can imagine this as a point that moves, on which the scrollrect is linked by an elastic. This targetYPosition is contrained by your limit. Then in your update you make the ScrollRectContent follow.

```
public void OnUserInput(float y) // I don't know how you actually do this. this is an example
{
    _targetYposition = y;
    if(_targetYposition > limit)
    {
        _targetYPosition = limit;
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    var currentPos = MyScrollRectContent.transform.localPosition;
    var y = 
        Vector3.Lerp(currentPos.y,
                     _targetYPosition, Time.deltaTime*_speed);
    MyScrollRectContent.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(currentPos.x, y, currentPos.z);
}
```

Note that this is a simple example aiming at hinting you in the right direction. You'll have to adapt it to your code. The elasticity will likely not look as you want either, so you might want to modify the Update function to create other effects